# Titanium HTTPClient timeout does not work

Tags: titanium

My app communicates to a server like this way:

```
var url = "http://my.server.com";
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload : function(e) {
        Ti.API.info("Received text: " + this.responseText);
        alert('success');
    },
    onerror : function(e) {
        Ti.API.debug(e.error);
        alert('error');
    },
    timeout : 5000
});

client.open("GET", url);
client.send();
```

When server is online all work fine but, when server is offline the `onerror` function never runs, even if 5000 mSec are past.

Is it a Titanium bug?
I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs fine here on my machine, under a 3.2GA Titanium SDK and a iOS 7.0.3 iPhone simulator.

Since I'm unable to reproduce the problem, you could:

- Check what version of SDK and emulator you are running, maybe updating either or both could help.
- Try to put a header (see code below)
- You could try to separate the callback functions when creating the request, this way you can at least debug if there's a problem when creating the request or why the callback function isn't called at all.

Something like this:

```
var url = "http://my.server.com";
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
client.setTimeout(5000);
client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
client.onerror = function(e) {
alert("Ops!");
};
client.send();
```

See if any of that works for you.

Comment: I have had better success with explicitly defining the time out as mentioned here. => client.setTimeout(5000);